# "submit" button is still clickable while using bootstrap validator plugin

Tags: validation, reactjs

I'm using bootstrap validator to validate the form in my react app, facing issues like the submit button is disabled but still clickable in the form, I want to make the button non clickable until the form gets validated. I added the disabled property but its not getting enabled once the form is valid.Below is my code.. Can anyone help here

```
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
  <div className="form-group">
    <div className="col-xs-5" id="form" style={{display:'none'}}>
      {this.renderForm(this.props.fld_dtl_da)}
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.ClearForm}>Clear</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button type="submit" disabled='disabled' className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.HandleClick}>Submit</button>
      <br/><br/>
    </div>
    <div id="url" class="alert alert-info" style={{display:'none'}}>
      <Confirmation message={this.state.message}/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```